# OpenGL: is it legal to attach a shader to a program that is in a valid linked state?

Tags: opengl

I've searched for a definitive answer to this but to no avail. The OpenGL specs seem to be silent on this, but that may be due to my inexperience in reading them.
I am not concerned with how implementations behave with regard to this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUseProgram.xhtml):

> While a program object is in use, applications are free to modify
>   attached shader objects, compile attached shader objects, **attach
>   additional shader** objects, and detach or delete shader objects. None
>   of these operations will affect the executables that are part of the
>   current state. However, relinking the program object that is currently
>   in use will install the program object as part of the current
>   rendering state if the link operation was successful...

So yes, it is legal, and it will have no effect until you relink the program.

And relink the current program automatically install the new version.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the important concept is one of current state and that you can do much to the 'external' objects that are associated with a program without changing the state of the current context. It is only when you link the program that the changes become part of the new current state. I should guess that one does not need to call glUseProgram after the relink as the program object is part of the 'state' and is not affected by the relink? This OpenGL state stuff is hard to follow from the docs!

Comment: See it as "we prepare a package" from the CPU side and then "we send a copy of it to the GPU" when it's ready (link process).

Comment: Gotcha. Nice, simple way of looking at it. Thanks. I've found looking at the docs better than the specs. It's just knowing what function calls change state.